# Python platform settings in NetBeans don't work

Tags: python, macos, netbeans, import, netbeans-8

I am trying to use Netbeans 8.1 on OSX 10.9 for my first Python project an got a similar problem as [import argparse fails, some setup/path issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898468/import-argparse-fails-some-setup-path-issue). I get this *ImportError* when trying to import any libraries:

```
File ".../hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

The same classic program can be run in command window by `python hello.py` or `python3 hello.py`.

I added `import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)` command in the beginning of my program to see the path. It shows, that NetBeans 8.1 doesn't follow the platform and path selections from *Tools > Python Platforms*.

I changed *Python 2.7.10* or *Python 3.5* as the selected (and default) platform, but the `sys.path` is always the same which refers to python2.7. That is always different from the ones defined in *Python Path* tab. (Restarting IDE did not help.)

I need to change the active path, what can I do?

Comment: Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200685/netbeans-not-allowing-python-2-6-as-default-platform-forcing-jython2-5?rq=1 refers to older problems in selecting _Python Platforms_. I can't believe nobody else has not tried to edit sys.path since 2010. – Is there a way to use a _virtualenv_ with Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

The project platform must be set in *Project properties* window. The *Python Platform Manager* settings do not affect to any existing projects!